# Append a vector to end of a list of vectors (ie, keeping the structure of the vector you are appending intact)

Tags: r, list, vector, append

I have a vector like:

```
a = list(c(1,2), c(3,4))
```

I want to append a vector c(5, 6) to the end of “**a**”, such that “**a**”  looks like:

```
a = list(c(1,2), c(3,4), c(5,6))
```

I have tried:

```
list(a, c(5,6))
```

and

```
append(a, c(5,6))
```

*Both of which completely destroy the structure of c(5,6) that I want to keep*  :(((

**How to do such a simple operation in R??**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier option is assignment to increase the length of the original `list`

```
a[[length(a) + 1]] <- c(5, 6)
```

---

Or wrap the `vector` with `list` and `append`.   Here, we are playing with two `list`.  So `append` will append the new `list` element as a single unit and we have a new list of length 3

```
append(a, list(c(5, 6)))
```

or with `c`.  Just to note that `append` is using `c` internally with some added functionalities to place the new element on a particular location (if needed)

```
c(a, list(c(5, 6)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 5 6
```

---

The issue with

```
list(a, c(5,6))
```

is that it creates a `list` with a `list` of length 2 where the first element is already a `list` and the second a normal vector.  In effect, we get a nested `list` for the 'a' elements

while the

```
append(a, c(5,6))
```

adds each element of the vector as new `list` element.  So, we get a new `list` of `length` 4 with the 3rd and 4th element having a length of 1

Comment: Thanks. I have considered this approach, but it requires tracking index. Any way to do it without the index??  If not, I’ll gladly accept the answer. Btw, I have upvoted your answer regardless. Thanks

Comment: @ppp I added 3 approaches.  Hopefully, the other approach works

Comment: Perfect, thanks for kind edits. Accepted! — I have to wait 11 minutes. Will do it in 11 minutes :)